# Quotient of space and a group of maps, Riemann surfaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I've been attempting to study Riemann surfaces, and I have continuously run into this notion which eludes me. I see people write things like $
\mathbb H / <z\mapsto z+1>$ or $\mathbb D / PSL$. I know what all these things are individually, but I don't understand how someone takes a quotient of a space and some maps (as opposed to say, treating the space as a group and taking the quotient over a normal subgroup). The end result of this is hopefully understanding how people come up with the "isomorphism maps" that are discussed in this context.

Can someone spell this out a little bit for me? The whole issue feels opaque to me.

Comment: Take a look at the last example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_%28topology%29#Examples).  $\mathcal{H}/\text{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ is an orbit space as described in the link.

Comment: Okay so if I had a particular case, like let's say instead of $\mathbb H$ above I had $\mathbb C$.  Then I identify all the points in the orbit of the map above. So how do I determine the ismorphism map? From similar examples I've seen, people say it is some kind of exponential.

Answer (score 2):

Say $G$ is a group of bijections of the set $X$. For $x,y\in X$ say $x\sim y$ if $x=gy$ for some $g\in G$. Then $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $X$, and $X/G$ is the same thing as the set $X/\sim$ of equivalences classes.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose a group $G$ acts (on the left) on a set $X$, so we have a map
\begin{align*}
G \times X &\to X\\
(g,x) &\mapsto gx \, .
\end{align*}
Given $x \in X$, consider its [*orbit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbits_and_stabilizers) $Gx = \{gx : g \in G\}$.  These orbits partition $X$, so we can define the quotient $G \backslash X = \{Gx : x \in X\}$ as the set of orbits.  (I write $G \backslash X$ rather than $X/G$ because $G$ is acting on the left.)

If $X$ is a topological space and $G$ is a topological group and acting continuously on $X$, i.e., the map
\begin{align*}
G \times X &\to X\\
(g,x) &\mapsto gx
\end{align*}
is continuous, then we can upgrade $G \backslash X$ to a topological space by giving it the [quotient topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_%28topology%29) as follows.  We have a quotient map
\begin{align*}
\pi: X &\to G \backslash X\\
x &\mapsto Gx
\end{align*}
that sends $x$ to its orbit, and we define the topology on $G \backslash X$ to be the strongest topology such that $\pi$ is continuous.  That is, $U \subseteq G \backslash X$ is open iff $\pi^{-1}(U) \subseteq X$ is open.

Let's look at a geometric-flavored example.  The group $\text{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ acts on the upper half-plane by Möbius transformations:
\begin{align*}
\text{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R}) \times \mathcal{H} &\to \mathcal{H}\\
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix} \cdot
z &= \frac{az + b}{cz + d} \, .
\end{align*}
Then
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \cdot z = z + 1
$$
so it acts as $T(z) = z+1$.  I claim that $\langle T \rangle \backslash \mathcal{H}$ is homeomorphic to an infinite cylinder.  To see this, we find a *fundamental domain* for the action, i.e., a set of representative points in $\mathcal{H}$ so that each orbit has exactly one representative.  In this case $\{z \in \mathcal{H} : 0 \leq \Re(z) < 1\}$, is such a set.  Since $T$ identifies the left and right edges of this domain, then we get a cylinder as the quotient $\langle T \rangle \backslash \mathcal{H}$.

For another example, take the subgroup $\text{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) \leq \text{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ and form $\text{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z})\backslash \mathcal{H}$.  This has a nice fundamental domain as shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group#Tessellation_of_the_hyperbolic_plane).  This yields a funny looking quotient that is homeomorphic to a sphere minus a point.

Comment: I understand what you're saying! I guess I don't see then why $\mathbb C / <z \mapsto z+1>$ is isomorphic to the punctured plane and not the infinite cylinder in the same way you outline.

Comment: The punctured plane and an infinite cylinder are homeomorphic.  The unit disc is homeomorphic to the plane via $x \mapsto \frac{x}{1 - |x|}$, so the punctured disc is homeomorphic to the punctured plane.  The punctured disc is homeomorphic to an open cylinder (just stretch out the puncture and "stand it up"), which is homeomorphic to an infinite cylinder.